# ionic capacitor android gradle sync failed issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using capacitor 2.0 for my ionic android project. But every time when I run the app on the android device I get the following errors

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
> file:/D:/client/mobile_app/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml;
> lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 49; Element type "application" must be
> followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
>
> Failed to parse XML in
> D:\client\mobile_app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Here is android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest package="capacitor.android.plugins"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android">
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> // error on this line

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
</manifest>
```

Please view the line number 5 application tag. Capacitor every time ads `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` twice that too without space. I manually need to remove the second one every time to get rid of the error.

Why capacitor is adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic = "true"` twice.

List of Cordova plugins

```
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-cleartext": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sms-receive": {},
      "com.razorpay.cordova": {}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: probably some plugin is adding the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and capacitor also adds `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` if you are using live reload. Which plugins are you using?

Comment: Ohh. I am using capacitor live reload.

Comment: yeah, but it adds one of them, which cordova plugins are you using that might be adding the other one?

Comment: I have edited the question and added list of Cordova plugins

Comment: But I can't see any plugin adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: it's added by `cordova-plugin-cleartext`

Comment: Okay. So how to prevent it from adding it?

Comment: I've sent a pull request so it doesn't get duplicated, but you can remove that plugin entirely, if you need to use cleartext traffic you can manually edit your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` instead of using a plugin

Comment: okay manually editing AndroidManifest.xml everytime is not a good solution

Comment: No, I mean the app's `AndroidManifest.xml`, you only have to edit it once to add the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and it won't go away

Comment: But I already have it in App's AndroidManifest.xml file. I will try removing it. But as pe my knowledge it won't allow cleartext traffic then

Comment: No, don't remove it, the problem is not in the app's AndroidManifest.xml, is in the AndroidManifest.xml in capacitor-cordova-android-plugins folder, those are different files

Comment: Yes. I have to remove it every time from capacitor-cordova-android-plugins

Comment: I'm telling you those are different files, you have to add it to the app's AndroidManifest.xml and uninstall `cordova-plugin-cleartext`, if you uninstall it, it won't be duplicated anymore